# Dysplaying the bits of a number

Tags: c, bit

I created a program which is supposed to receive an integer and return the binary representation of that number. Now i would like to add a function to count how many "1" are near in the number, that's where i am having some troubles, example:

INPUT: 123
-> 0b01111011 -> 4 (Because there are 4 near "1")

To do that, i need to store in a variable the output of my current script, but i can't go beyond that, since i'm using putchar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displayBits(unsigned int value); // prototype

int main(void)
{ 
   unsigned int x; // variable to hold user input
   printf("%s", "Enter a nonnegative int: ");
   scanf("%u", &x);
   displayBits(x);
} 
// display bits of an unsigned int value
void displayBits(unsigned int value)
{  



   // define displayMask and left shift 31 bits
   unsigned int displayMask = 1 << 7; 
   printf("%10u = ", value);
   printf("0b");


   // loop through bits 
   for (unsigned int c = 1; c <= 8; ++c) {

      putchar(value & displayMask ? '1' : '0');
      value <<= 1;


   } 
   putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum cluster of set bits within a binary number?

Comment: @Myst let's say that the output is 01110110. I must say how many "1" are near, in 01110110 there are 3 near "1" and then 2 near "1", i hope it's clearer now

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your example, you say there are 3 and than 2... do you want the script to remember the 3 (the maximum only) or do you need all results?

Comment: No, only the higher result

Comment: Apparently, you only need 256 values. Try a lookup array: `static int lookup[] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, ... 8};` them simply print the pre computed value: `printf("%d has %d 1-bits in succession.\n", value, lookup[value]);`

Comment: I got it, thanks @pmg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to count the maximum number of adjacent bits that are set to 1, so can do so as follows.

Have a counter that keeps track of how may '1' bits in a row you've found.  When you find a '1' increment it, when you find a '0' set it to 0.  You also need a variable that keeps track of the longest run.  If the current is bigger than the longest run, set the longest to the current.

```
int current_run = 0, longest_run = 0;
while (displayMask) {
   if (value & displayMask) {
       current_run++;
       if (current_run > longest_run) {
           longest_run = current_run;
       }
       putchar('1');
   } else {
       current_run = 0;
       putchar('0');
   }

   displayMask >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: I would use MAX instead of `if`.

Comment: I would reconsider the direction on the bit shifting... (just print it all at once with a `char buffer[8]`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was thinking about, unfortunately i'm still a beginner and i had some difficulties getting to it. Thank you @dbush!